# How to update list of tuple

Tags: python

```
list_data = [(4,5),(6,7)] 
output should be [(4,5),(11,7)]
```

So i want to update 6 to 11.

Here list_data is list of tuple and tuple is immutable data type, so we can not update tuple. but my requirement
 is to update. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: How do you know to update `6` to `11`? In other words, what is your general algorithm for replacement given an arbitrary `list_data`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use lists instead of tuples, since you need to update them?

Comment: tuples are immutable - you can replace the tuple (6,7) with a new tuple (11,7) though.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: " tuple is immutable data type, so we can not update tuple. but my requirement is to update."- if your requirements are really that restrictive then you'll have to hack CPython, however, in a practical sense it's very likely re-building the tuple or using a list would be just fine

Comment: Hey @praveen-kumar did my answer on this one helped? Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), try using a nested list instead!

That way you will be able to .append() or .pop() any element on any list.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace. Lists are mutable so you can do just that.

```
for i,(a, b) in enumerate(list_data):
  if a == 6:
    list_data[i] = (11, b)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer that you feel worked best for you.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the tuple to list and change the value and then update the result.

```
list_data = [(4,5),(6,7)] 
tpl = list(list_data[1])
tpl[0] = 11
list_data[1] = tuple(tpl)
```