# Is there a way to insert values into a list of tuple in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a empty list of tuple and I wish to enter values inside that tuple.

The desired output is :

`lst = [()]  -->   lst = [(1,2,'string1','string2',3)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update list of tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924481/how-to-update-list-of-tuple)

Answer (score 1):

A tuple is, by definition, unchangable.
You may want to replace that tuple with a new one like this:

```
lst = [()]
lst[0] = ("item1", "item2")
```

In this way you are *replacing* the origina tuple with a new one with the desired items. If the tuple is not empty you can do:

```
lst[0] = (*lst[0], "new item")
```

Here you are unpacking the values of the old tuple (`*lst[0]` is equal to `"item1", "item2"` in this example) and adding new items.

Note that if you are working with variable data maybe `tuple` is not the best data structure to use in this case.

Comment: In such a case which is best data structure to use instead of tuple?

Comment: @Vanshaj It really depends on your requirements. If you simply want to append items you can simply use a `list`, if you want a stack you may be looking for a `deque` or a `list`, if you don't care about order and don't want duplicates you probably want to use a `set`.

Comment: Here you can find useful information about data structures in python: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#)

Answer (score 0):

you can't, A tuple is a collection that is ordered and immutable.

though, you can create a new tuple with the same name